# Custom DataBindingComponent per Activity

Tags: android, android-databinding

I can create a [BindingAdapter](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/databinding/BindingAdapter.html) like this:

```
public class MyClass {

  @BindingAdapter("bindItems")
  public static void bindItems(ViewPager viewPager, List<String> items) {

  }
}
```

Now if I dont want this binding method to be static, but an instance method of the enclosing class, I just omit the static keyword:

```
public class MyClass {

  @BindingAdapter("bindItems")
  public void bindItems(ViewPager viewPager, List<String> items) {

  }
}
```

but then I have to provide a method for the databinding framework to obtain an instance of my class which contains the `@BindingAdapter` method (`MyClass`).

This is possible with a custom implementation of the [DataBindingComponent](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/databinding/DataBindingComponent.html) which looks like:

```
public class MyDatabindingComponent implements android.databinding.DataBindingComponent {

  public getMyClass() {
    return new MyClass(); 
  }
}
```

and is used when setting the Activity's content view like this:

```
DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_test, new MyDatabindingComponent);
```

**So far so good... But!**
This custom DataBindingComponent has to create instances of classes with non-static `@BindingAdapter` methods for the entire app.

This can quickly get out of hand, especially when the creation of instances is not as trivial as in my example. I know I can use DI, e.g. Dagger to more easily create the `MyDataBindingComponent`, still I'm not happy with injecting lots of stuff into my Activities of which much isn't really needed in that particular Activity.

Example for a gotten-out-of-hand DataBindingComponent

```
public class MyDatabindingComponent implements android.databinding.DataBindingComponent {

  MyClass myClass;
  MyClass2 myClass2;
  MyClass3 myClass3;

  @Inject
  public MyDatabindingComponent(MyClass myClass, MyClass2 myClass2, MyClass3 myClass3) {
    this.myClass = myClass;
    this.myClass2 = myClass2;
    this.myClass3 = myClass3;
  }

  public getMyClass() {   // needed in Activity A
    return myClass; 
  }

  public getMyClass2() {   // needed in Activity B
    return myClass2; 
  }

  public getMyClass3() {   // needed in Activity C
    return myClass3; 
  }
}
```

Is there any way to make these DataBindingComponent per-activity so it has only to provide the instances that are needed in the activity I use it in?